# Setup Command Line Parameters - What command to use to display no icons on desktop?

Tags: command-line, installation

Hi I would like to ask if I can use the command line parameter /NOICONS command line to display no icons on desktop during and after the installation? will it shows no icons on desktop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not obvious, I assume this relates to Inno setup? I don't have an inno setup available to test with at the moment, but I assume you should be able to use /NOICONS to disable the default install of the shortcuts. Check the documentation here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline